Pandas replace warning
I'd like to replace -999 values in my dataframe by nan, it works but it generates warnings.
df['my_column'].replace(-999.0, np.nan, inplace=True)
df.loc[:, 'my_column'] = df.loc[:, 'my_column'].replace(-999.0, np.nan)
df[occurences[question]['column']].replace({-999.0: np.nan}, inplace=True)
I tried these 3 lines which generates the following warning:
ChainedAssignmentError: A value is trying to be set on a copy of a DataFrame or Series through chained assignment using an inplace method.
When using the Copy-on-Write mode, such inplace method never works to update the original DataFrame or Series, because the intermediate object on which we are setting values always behaves as a copy.
For example, when doing 'df[col].method(value, inplace=True)', try using 'df.method({col: value}, inplace=True)' instead, to perform the operation inplace on the original object.
What is the correct syntax to avoid the warning ?
Thanks

You should use df['my_column'] = df['my_column'].replace(-999.0, np.nan)

Your error might come from what you were doing previously. Just try to use df = df.copy() before your current error. If this gets rid of the error, then you have to check the code that comes before.

As mozway (I prefer such solution), or as the error message tell you (but I find uglier): df.replace({'my_column': {-999.0: np.nan}}, inplace=True)

@GiacomoCatenazzi: this works without Warning. Thanks.
if I need to replace on various columns (in a variable list), a part from a loop is there a clean syntax ?

The same syntax, just add other columns. It is a dictionary of column_names
